# How can you draw a slope field if $y$ is dependent on $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a lot intuitive trouble understanding this seemingly simple concept. Let's say I have the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$$

In this case, $y$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent variable, and that the solution is some function $y=y(x)$.

That would mean that in the original equation, $f(x,y)$ would just be $f(x,y(x))$ and that $y$ is dependent on $x$.
If that is case, how can on draw a *slope field* and vary $x$ and $y$ however one wants to like independent variables, when the value of $y$ is supposed to be dependent on the value of $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the problem : let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$.
Then, according to Picard-Lindelof theorem, the following initial value problem has a unique solution defined on an open interval $I_K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ :

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 y'(x)=f(x,y)\\ 
 y(0)=K, K\in \mathbb{R} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Note that the interval $I_K$ may depend on $K$, hence the notation.

Each $K \in \mathbb{R}$ defines an unique solution. Now, imagine you take several $K$, and for each one, you draw the unique solution. What you are doing is drawing the beginning of a slope field.

To sum up, the fonction $y=y(x)$ you are talking about can be seen as $y(x,K)$.
The first one is unequivocally defined on a "well-posed" initial value problem while the second is more general.